# ¿Cómo seleccionar un RepositoryItemCheckEdit con doble clic?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017, devexpress

Estoy trabajando en un formulario Winform en C# y Devexpress, quisiera saber si se puede y cómo hacer que en un elemento `RepositoryItemCheckEdit` se pueda seleccionar solo con doble clic y deshabilitar el clic.

Comment: Has contactado el equipo de [Soporte de DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create)? o no tienes licencia vigente?

Comment: No tengo licencia vigente.

Comment: Entiendo, puedes describir de forma mas clara el escenario, para intentar proporcionarte una solución, en que parte estas usando el `RepositoryItemCheckEdit` en `GridView` o `Barra de Tíluto` o donde?

Comment: Lo estoy utilizando dentro de un GridView, por default el RepositoryItemCheckEdit cambia de valor al hacer un clic, lo que requiero es que cambie de valor con doble clic y no con un solo clic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad no se el motivo por el que desees cambiar el comportamiento predeterminado del objeto, pero logré que funcione de una forma muy tonta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haciendo un rejuego con el uso de la propiedad `Tag`  del objeto `RepositoryItemCheckEdit` para no usar variables, puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
private void repositoryItemCheckEdit1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    repositoryItemCheckEdit1.Tag = 0;
}

private void repositoryItemCheckEdit1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    repositoryItemCheckEdit1.Tag = null;
}

private void repositoryItemCheckEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    repositoryItemCheckEdit1.Tag = null;
}

private void repositoryItemCheckEdit1_EditValueChanging(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = (repositoryItemCheckEdit1.Tag == null);
}
```

**Explicación:**

> Como puedes ver fue necesario manejar 4 eventos para lograr este objetivo, lo que hago es asignar `Tag = null` cuando se hace un solo click, o cuando cambia el valor del `CheckEdit` de modo que no permita cambiar el estado del objeto, y cuando se hace DobleClick le asigno el valor 0 (puede asignar lo que desees, solo es como validación) para que el evento `EditValueChanging` haga la magia en: `e.Cancel = (repositoryItemCheckEdit1.Tag == null);` solo permitirá el cambio de estado cuando el valor de la propiedad `Tag` no sea `null`

---

Estoy seguro que debe haber una manera mas práctica de hacer esto, como el estatus de tu licencia no esta vigente, te recomiendo que traduzcas y formules esta misma pregunta en [StackOverFlow Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), donde posiblemente el usuario [DevExpress Team](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380926/devexpress-team), o el usuario [DmitryG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1010363/dmitryg) que pertenece a la empresa DevExpress puedan buscar una mejor solución para ti.

Saludos!